# how to get values from interface set by adapter in main activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, interface, sharedpreferences, adapter

how can i get cart item quantity from recycler view adapter to its parent activity.

Define interface, set item count in recycler view adapter and  implements interface in main activity

```
   interface OnItemClick {
           void onClick (String value);
   }


   private OnItemClick mCallback;
    public VegeHomeAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<ModelTopProd> mData, OnItemClick listener) {
           this.mData = mData;
           this.ctx = ctx;
           this.mCallback = listener;
       }
   int total_items = Integer.parseInt(preferenceHelper.getCARTNO());

                                   total_items+=1;
                                   preferenceHelper.putCARTNO(""+total_items);
                                   mCallback.onClick(""+preferenceHelper.getCARTNO());


        public class Home extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, OnItemClick {

       public interface OnItemClickListener {
               void onItemClick(View view, int position);
           }

   }
```

```
How to set values to text view TextView qtyTV; got from adapter
```

Answer (score 1):

Adapter:

```
public VegeHomeAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<ModelTopProd> mData, OnItemClick listener) {
    this.mData = mData;
    this.ctx = ctx;
    this.mCallback = listener;

    interface OnItemClick {
       void onClick (String value);
       void getTotalItems(int totalItems);
   }
}
  int total_items = Integer.parseInt(preferenceHelper.getCARTNO());

  total_items+=1;
  preferenceHelper.putCARTNO(""+total_items);
  mCallback.onClick(""+preferenceHelper.getCARTNO());
}
```

Home:

```
public class Home extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, OnItemClick {

  private int totalItems = 0

  @Override 
  public onClick(String itemName) { 
     //your implementation
  }

  @Override
  public void getTotalItems(int total)  {
      totalItems = total;
  }



}
```

Comment: I got error by adding getTotalItems(), that Method does not overrides method from its superclass

Comment: Do you have the method in the adapter interface?

Comment: I have interface in VegeHomeAdapter like  public VegeHomeAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<ModelTopProd> mData, OnItemClick listener) {
        this.mData = mData;
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.mCallback = listener;


    }

    interface OnItemClick {
        void onClick (String value);
        void getTotalItems(int totalItems);
    }